# Why was the fragment called before?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

Consider this part of code of the TabbedActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER))
        {
            case 1:
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                return rootView;

            case 2:
                View rootView2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"FRAGMENT 2 BUILT WHEN WE VIEW FRAGMENT 1! ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return rootView2;

            case 3:
                View rootView3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                return rootView3;

            default:
                View rootView0 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                return rootView0;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "SECTION 1";
            case 1:
                return "SECTION 2";
            case 2:
                return "SECTION 3";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

When we are in case 1, the case 2 was called and if I put a Toast which I want to see in the second fragment, I look it in the first because the second was built before. I want to call the creation of a fragment only when the fragment was visualized in my TabbedActivity. How can I do this?

Comment: "When we are in case 1, the case 2 was called" eh? Don't debug with Toasts neither, learn to use the logcat.

Comment: @weston The fragment was built always before the view physical, for example the fragment number 2 was built when we look at the fragment number 1. I want to build the fragment number 2 when we view physically the fragment 2. Did you understand me?

Comment: what makes you think frag2 is build when frag one is on screen? nothing in your code proves it

Comment: No, I don't follow at all "When we are in case 1, the case 2 was called" that's impossible, so maybe you can rephase that.

Comment: @OlegBogdanov I view this because I inserted a Toast and every fragment was prepared before its view

Comment: oh if I understand you are saying object of frag was created before the view was inflated? but thats how it supposed to be, view is just a subobject of fragment, it cant be born before the parent

Comment: @weston Oh no, I express me bad...I wanted to say when we are in fragment 1, the fragment 2 was built

Comment: OK, well we can't see anything like that from the code supplied. At the same time, supply the minimal code, these 8 cases are not all needed to show this issue are they?

Comment: @OlegBogdanov We are in onCreateView. We visualize the fragment number one, at the same time the fragment number 2 was built. I saw this with a Toast

Comment: give us some Toast-ing code please

Comment: @weston We are in a TabbedActivity and the problem is that the fragment x was built when we view the fragment x-1

Comment: @OlegBogdanov All right

Comment: @OlegBogdanov Well, you have to create a simply TabbedActivity. Then, you have to write a switch like in the code so you'll view the different fragments. Afterwards, you have to put a toast in the second case (make only 3 fragments for your test) and then start the app. You'll watch the toast which you put in the case 2 when you'll view the first fragment!

Comment: no no no sorry, its YOU who have to paste some code ;)

Comment: @weston I hope you'll understand

Comment: @OlegBogdanov All right, I'll poste the code which you'll copy in a new project and then you'll start it so you'll watch what I say

Comment: @OlegBogdanov Now, copy and paste the code and run the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TabbedActivity using ViewPager in core to provide sliding behavior. As I understand, you want Fragments were instantiated only when it becomes visible. But, ViewPager always load fragments(or items) with 1 prefetched item by default. You can change that amount but 1 is minimum. Here is the code from ViewPager class:

```
public void setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit) {
    if (limit < DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Requested offscreen page limit " + limit + " too small; defaulting to "
                + DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES);
        limit = DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES;
    }
    if (limit != mOffscreenPageLimit) {
        mOffscreenPageLimit = limit;
        populate();
    }
}
```

So, with ViewPager you can't reach your goal. You can use TabLayout to implement similar behavior

XML layout with TabLayout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#000000"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tab 1" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tab 2" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tab 3" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tab 4" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You should also set NoActionBar theme for this Activity

Activity code:

```
    public class TabbedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SparseArrayCompat<Fragment> fragments = new SparseArrayCompat<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabbed_activity);
        setTitle("");
        fragments.put(0, new Fragment()); //Here you need to instantiate your fragments
        fragments.put(1, new Fragment()); // instead of new Fragment()
        fragments.put(2, new Fragment()); // like new Tab1Fragment()
        fragments.put(3, new Fragment());
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                changeFragment(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
        changeFragment(0);
    }

    private void changeFragment(int position) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment fragment = fragments.get(position);
        String transactionTag = fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
        if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 &&
                fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getName()
                        .equalsIgnoreCase(transactionTag)) {
            return;
        }
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment, transactionTag);
        transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

TabLayout is very flexible, read more at here(https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout)

Comment: Yes, you understood me! How can I use a TabLayout like a ViewPager?

Comment: Look, TabLayout will not give you full behavior of ViewPager, because ViewPager ALWAYS use preload to provide smooth sliding. With TabLayout you'll have only controls to switch fragments on tab click but not on slide events. It will provide you similar UI but little different interaction

Comment: How can I create a Tab Layout which has got the same appearance of a TabbedActivity?

Comment: Can you post the code of the class too?

Comment: Sure, see edited XML & added Activity code

Comment: How can I set a layout for a fragment?

Comment: You should inflate view from layout inside onCreateView() method of your Fragment and return this view.

Comment: Do I have to do  `if(position==1/2/3) {getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,container,false);}`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132083/discussion-between-curio-and-vortexheatkiller).